# Facebook application that allow users to upload image to the application album

Tags: php, image, upload, facebook

I am trying to develope a facebook application that allows the users to create an album in my application and upload photos to it. I read some articles but those were very confusing. Could anyone tell me where I can get some simple article regarding this. I have no idea where to start from.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using facebook php sdk ?

Comment: yes I am using facebook php sdk.

Comment: Hi,
I was stuck with the same thing. Thanks for the help. What I would like to know is that how can the album for the app be crated then? does it have to be done manually? or can there be a script for it? Thanks for the help

Comment: Hmmmm, it may not be possible. I did good rnd on it but no luck

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is getting the user authenticated and with the [corresponding permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) into your app (you will need special permissions to upload a picture into his albums, or creating a new one).

Once you have the permissions and therefore, the auth token, you can upload pictures by making post requests to the Graph API.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

Look at the bottom where it shows you an example using cURL.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I want to allow users to create an album in my application and upload photos to it(not into the user's album).

Comment: It's not possible to add photos to an album that's not yours. You can tag someone into a photo, but not add photos to his albums.

Comment: I mean I am not adding photos into the album. The user is. I just want to allow the user to create an album and add photos into it. Is it possible? Can it be done using the regular php file upload?

Comment: Well, I think I did not explain myself correctly. An user only can upload photos into his own albums, not anyone's (user, page, etc) else .

Comment: Thanks Manuel. Now I shall look for some other alternatives. I shall create a form for the user to upload photos to my server and shall post it myself into my application. Wont that work? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Thanks Manuel. Sorry for the late reply. Actually I have been trying to post comment to this thread for the past 1 week. Don't know why I was not able to. I hope you have completed the application.